# What are m-placed relation symbols and function symbols?

Tags: logic, model-theory

In [This Model Theory book](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/model_theory.pdf), Weiss refers to "m-placed function symbols" and "m-placed relation symbols". Are these just supposed to be functions of $m$ objects and relations between $m$ objects? I'm having some trouble digesting this. I think I am having more trouble understanding the m-placed relations, though.

Answer (score 2):

They're symbols that are intended to *denote* such functions and relations; they're not functions or relations themselves.

Comment: Right, thanks. I'm just having a bit of trouble understanding multi-valued relations, though... it's essentially a way to show that $m$ objects are related under some operation?

Comment: If $\underline{\text{R}}$ is, say, a 3-place relation symbol, then you can write formulas of the form $\underline{\text{R}}(x,y,z)$ (where $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ are variables, constant symbols, or other terms), and you can use those as subformulas of sentences or other formulas.  None of these formulas mean anything specific until you have a model with (among other things) an actual 3-place relation $R$ that you will be using as the interpretation of the symbol $\underline{\text{R}}.$  In fact, the meaning of these formulas will be different in different models.

Comment: Oh I see. For some reason, I was under the impression that $R(x_1 \cdots x_n)$ was something like an equivalence class, under some binary relation $\sim$, such that for all $x_i$ and $x_j$, $x_i \sim x_j$. I understand now, though, thank you!

Comment: I didn't have room to include this in my previous comment, but a 3-place relation $R$ in a model with universe $A$ is just a subset of $A \times A \times A,$  where we say that $R(x,y,z)$ is true iff $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ belongs to that subset.

Comment: Oh, that actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just think of a relation as a collection of ordered $m$-tuples.  Items $a1$, $a2$, ..., $am$ are related under the $m$-place relation R iff the tuple ($a1$, $a2$, ..., $am$) is in R.  *[they don't have to be related 'under some operation' to be related]*

For example, there is the 3-place relation which I will call $Pyth()$ : the numeric triplet ($a$,$b$,$c$) is in $Pyth()$ iff $a+b=c$.  When considering $Pyth()$ as a relation, we don't need to involve the '+' or '=' if we don't want to, we can just think about the triplets '(3,4,5)', '(5,12,13)', etc., by themselves (as a collection).  Model Theory takes that perspective.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Set Theory an $n$-ary relation on a set $S$ is some (any) subset of $S^n.$ And an $n$-ary function on $S$ is a function from $S^n$ into $S.$ In Model Theory an $n$-ary relation and $n$-ary function symbols  are arbitrary objects that are "interpreted" by a model $\mathbb M=(M,...)$ as  $n$-ary relations  and $n$-ary functions on $M.$ The "..." in $\mathbb M=(M,...)$ is a "list" of the interpretations by $\mathbb  M$ of all the relation symbols and function symbols of the language

Comment: I took courses in set theory , and model theory under  William Weiss at U. of Toronto. He had a difficulty which he said was embarrassing for a mathematician : An allergy to chalk.  He had a large wheeled greaseboard.

Comment: ^ oh my, haha...

Comment: What about using whiteboards instead?

Comment: @user21820   I think whiteboard is indeed the more accurate term for what he used